# Quotient space is isometrically isomorphic to $C(F)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let $F$ be a closed subset of $X$. If $W = \{f \in C(X) : f(x) = 0  \text{ for all } x \in F\}$, show that $C(X)/W$ is isometrically isomorphic to $C(F)$.
($C(X)$ is the space of continuous real-valued functions on $X$.)

Comment: "isometrically isometric?"

Comment: The comment here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123133/hahn-banach-theorem#comment284673_123133 seems relevant

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the obvious map $C(X) \to C(F)$ (restriction). Prove that it is a quotient map (i. e. maps the open unit ball onto the open unit ball) and determine its kernel ...